# Speeding up einsum for specific matrix and vector size

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have 2 arrays, one is of size:

```
A = np.random.uniform(size=(48, 1000000, 2))
```

and the other is

```
B = np.random.uniform(size=(48))
```

I want to do the following summation:

```
np.einsum("i, ijk -> jk", B, A)
```

as fast as possible.

The summation would need to be done tens of millions of times, so speed matters. At each iteration, `B` would change and `A` would stay the same. I have tried 2 options (see below) but both of them are comparable. Is there a way to speed it up?

Code:

```
import numpy as np

def computation_einsum(x,y):
    z = np.einsum("i, ijk -> jk", y, x)
    return z

def computation_dot(x,y):
    z = y @ x
    return z

A = np.random.uniform(size=(48, 1000000, 2))
B = np.random.uniform(size=(48))
C = A.transpose(1,0,2)
```

Timings:

```
%timeit -n 10 computation_einsum(A, B)
100 ms ± 238 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit -n 10 computation_dot(C, B)
107 ms ± 2.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I know that for larger matrices there are options which would make a difference, but I have these specific shapes and sizes.

Comment: `np.einsum("i, ijk -> jk", B, A, optimize=['einsum_path', (0, 1)])`

Comment: Using `np.float32` speeds up by ~2x.

Comment: Thank you, can you clarify the second comment of yours? Do you mean to use `dtype=np.float32` in `np.einsum`?

Comment: It seems beneficial to rearrange `A` so that the length-48 vectors contained in it are contiguous in memory. For some reason for me it was also faster to get rid of the size-2 axis. So basically: `A_ = A.transpose(1,2,0).copy(); result = A_.reshape(-1, 48).dot(B).reshape(-1, 2)`.

Comment: @John - No, to use *A* and *B* with dtype `np.float32` if possible.

Comment: Using `D=C.copy()` may help

Comment: `E = A.tranpose(1,2,0).copy()` and `E@B` gives me the best times.

Comment: Using a transposition is far from being optimal as 1. Numpy use an inefficient (sequential) transposition algorithm so far, 2. the output is written in a newly created array resulting in expensive page-faults, 3. transpositions are expensive (especially out-of-place ones) since the memory bandwidth is a scarce resource, 4. the OP operation is memory bound on most platform so the transposition is actually slower than doing directly the operation efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

By default `np.einsum` does not optimize computations done since the cost to perform optimizations can sometimes be bigger than the computation itself (especially for small arrays). You can solve this using:

```py
np.einsum("i, ijk -> jk", B, A, optimize='optimal')
```

With this, `np.einsum` use internally a BLAS implementation (like OpenBLAS by default on most system including on my machine) which is far more efficient: it should run in parallel and use faster SIMD instructions (especially on x86 with AVX instead of SSE).

This operation is mostly **memory bound** and the above solution succeed to reach a memory throughput of ~30 GiB/s while the peak is about ~40/s GiB. This is very good (for a generic Numpy code) but **sub-optimal**.

Note the solution of @MichaelSzczesny gives similar performance results (with 64-bit floats).

---

### Defeating OpenBLAS

While OpenBLAS is sub-optimal here, writing a faster code is far from being easy as such library is *aggressively optimized* to reach high-performance (AFAIK, they make use of architecture-specific kernels and even some hand-written assembly codes). That being said, they are written for generic cases and assume the computation is mostly compute bound which is not the case here.

A solution to defeat OpenBLAS is to write a **parallel Numba code solving your specific case** where: `B` has a small fixed size, the last dimension of `A` is always 2 and `A` is relatively big. Numba is a Python module that can compile specific Python codes to native binary using a **just-in-time compiler**.

The main idea is to virtually split `A` in blocks along the second dimension and then perform a **cache-friendly weighted sum** along the first dimension (that is not contiguously stored in memory). The code use assertions and compile-time constants so to help the compiler aggressively unrolling and vectorizing loops. The output matrix is passed in parameter of the function so not to pay the cost of expensive [page-faults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault). Here is the final code:

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

block_size = 1024
B_size = 48

@nb.njit(fastmath=True, inline='never')
def compute_block(A, B, out, iStart, iEnd, complete):
    n = A.shape[1]

    # Check everything is Ok and help the compiler 
    # to optimize the loops more aggressively.
    assert A.shape[0] == B_size
    assert A.shape[2] == 2
    assert out.shape[1] == 2
    assert B.size == B_size
    assert out.shape[0] == n

    for i in range(iStart, iEnd):
        out[i, 0] = out[i, 1] = 0.0
    for j in range(B_size):
        factor = B[j]

        # Help the compiler to perform (better) loop unrolling
        if complete:
            for i in range(iStart, iStart+block_size):
                out[i, 0] += A[j, i, 0] * factor
                out[i, 1] += A[j, i, 1] * factor
        else:
            for i in range(iStart, iEnd):
                out[i, 0] += A[j, i, 0] * factor
                out[i, 1] += A[j, i, 1] * factor

@nb.njit('void(float64[:,:,::1], float64[::1], float64[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(A, B, out):
    n = A.shape[1]

    # Parallel computation of many blocks
    for bi in nb.prange(n // block_size):
        iStart = bi * block_size
        iEnd = iStart + block_size
        compute_block(A, B, out, iStart, iEnd, True)

    # Remaining part
    bi = n // block_size
    iStart = bi * block_size
    if iStart < n:
        compute_block(A, B, out, iStart, n, False)

# Example of use:
A = np.random.uniform(size=(48, 1000000, 2))
B = np.random.uniform(size=(48))

C = np.empty((A.shape[1], 2), dtype=np.float64)
compute(A, B, C)
```

---

### Benchmark

Here are results on my i5-9600KF processor and a ~40 GiB DRAM:

```
np.einsum("i, ijk -> jk", B, A):                        54.4 ms
np.einsum("i, ijk -> jk", B, A, optimize='optimal'):    25.2 ms
compute(A, B, C)                                        19.5 ms
Theoretical optimal time (lower bound):                 18.6 ms
```

The final implementation succeed to reach a memory throughput of 38.2 GiB/s which is very close to the optimal on my machine.

Note that as pointed by @MichaelSzczesny, using 32-bit floats results in about 2 time faster timings since 32-bit floats takes 2 times less space in memory and the operation is memory bound. 32-bit floats are less precise though.

Comment: A related question to this answer: Have you found a way instead of assert, which only leads to better optimization instead of better optimization and probably costly checking of the array shapes?

Answer (score 1):

We can improve `matmul` by giving it arrays that it can pass 'intact' to the compiled code.  A transpose reorders the shape and strides, but does not change the underlying data.  `copy` takes time, but may be worth it if you are reusing `A` many times.

```
In [213]: C = A.transpose(1,0,2)
In [214]: D = C.copy()
```

Alternate transpose, putting `48` last:

```
In [215]: E = A.transpose(1,2,0).copy()
```

timings:

```
In [217]: timeit B@C
486 ms ± 347 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [218]: timeit B@D
272 ms ± 14.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [219]: timeit E@B
155 ms ± 1.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I'm a little surprised that this `einsum` is faster, since I thought it pass the calculation on to matmul in simple cases:

```
In [223]: timeit np.einsum('jki,i->jk', E,B)
127 ms ± 1.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

And for reference, on my machine:

```
In [228]: timeit np.einsum('i,ijk->jk', B,A)
361 ms ± 639 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It's worth playing with the optimize parameter.  The effect seems to vary with the numpy version, so I can't predict when it will help, but here:

```
In [229]: timeit np.einsum('i,ijk->jk', B,A, optimize=True)
195 ms ± 3.74 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

It doesn't help in the `E` case:

```
In [232]: timeit np.einsum('jki,i->jk', E,B,optimize=True)
129 ms ± 1.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Additionally, using `optimize=['einsum_path', (0, 1)],` with `np.einsum` slashes the time by about 50%.