# Calculate A * B * A' (`A @ B @ A.T`) in numpy with symmetry preservation

Tags: python, numpy, performance, linear-algebra, numba

I want to calculate the term `A * B * A'` for matrices `A` and `B`.
The `A'` is the transpose of `A`.

Is there an efficient way to calculate this on Python?

I can do `A @ B @ A.T` yet I want  something:

1. Which takes advantage of the symmetric for calculation.
2. Guarantees a symmetric result.

I have the most straight forward numba based code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, njit

A = np.random.rand(3, 3)
B = np.random.rand(3, 3)
B = B + B.T

@njit
def my_fun(A, B, C):
    for i in range(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(A.shape[1]):
            for k in range(B.shape[1]):
                for l in range(i, A.shape[1]):
                    C[i, l] += A[i, j] * B[j, k] * A[l, k]
                    
    for i in range(1, A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i):
            C[i, j] = C[j, i]
    
    return

C = np.zeros(shape = (A.shape[0], A.shape[0]))

my_fun(A, B, C)

np.all(C == C.T)
```

The output is symmetric.
Could we do better performance wise?

I also thought about fixing the symmetry of the numpy result by:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, njit

A = np.random.rand(10, 10)
B = np.random.rand(10, 10)
B = B + B.T

@njit
def symmetrize_mat(A):
    
    for i in range(1, A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i):
            A[i, j] = A[j, i]
    
    return


def my_faster_fun(A, B, C):
    C = np.matmul(A, B, out=C)
    C = np.matmul(C, A.T, out=C)
                    
    symmetrize_mat(C)
    
    return

C = np.zeros(shape = (A.shape[0], A.shape[0]))
D = A @ B @ A.T

my_faster_fun(A, B, C)

print(np.all(C == C.T))
print(np.all(D == D.T))
print(np.max(np.abs(C - D)))
```

I am looking for the fastest solution for small to medium sized matrices. Each dimension in the range 2-100.

Comment: Related: [Calculate "v^T A v" for a matrix of vectors v](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18541851/11082165)

Comment: Past SO have claimed that `matmul` can detect symmetry in A@A.T, and use a more efficient BLAS function.  But nothing in python/numpy will treat the double operation as one.

Comment: @Brian61354270,I saw the linked question before posting. It doesn't guarantee symmetry.

Comment: @hpaulj, I don't thing there is a blas operation for the above.

Comment: What is the size of the matrices? If `A` and `B` are sufficiently big, then AFAIK there is almost no benefit (performance-wise) of having the symmetry information, so `A @ B @ A.T` is close to be optimal (using parenthesis might help for non-squared matrices though).

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I'd say small to medium. Say in the range of 2 to 100 in each dimension.

Comment: Ok. In this case, the overhead of Numpy can be significant. Calling BLAS from C/Cython code should be pretty good for medium-sized matrices. For small ones (e.g. <16), neither BLAS nor Numpy can be really fast. In this case, I advise you to use your own implementation, typically written in C/Cython/Numba. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901637/speeding-up-einsum-for-specific-matrix-and-vector-size/71903188#71903188) is an example of fast matrix-multiplication in Numba for specific matrices.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, What about this specific form? How would you do it with einsum or numba?

Comment: @Mark don't ask Jerome to do the work for you. He already gave you good advices. People here can help you, fix mistakes, etc. but you need to show that you at least tried (some code).

Comment: @dankal444, I don't see how multiple matrix products guarantees the symmetry.

Comment: @dankal444, I added my try which I'm pretty sure is far from being well optimized.

Comment: Thank you for your try. I will write an answer showing a more efficient implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The provided code run in **`O(n**4)`** while two matrix multiplication runs in **`O(n**3)`**. Thus, 2 matrix multiplications are certainly significantly faster. One can try to change the order of the loop and then factorize some computation but the result will probably be similar to 2 multiplication matrix. A simpler approach consists in writing the code performing 2 multiplication matrix, then optimizing by swapping loops to make it more SIMD-friendly, then adapt it to compute only the upper triangular part for the last multiplication matrix. The intermediate matrix can actually be computed line by line (which is a bit more efficient for large matrices). The lower triangular part can be computed like you did in the provided implementation.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
@njit
def faster_fun(A, B, C):
    # Constraints coming from the 2 matrix multiplications
    assert A.shape[1] == B.shape[0] and A.shape[1] == B.shape[1]

    n, m = A.shape
    line = np.zeros(m)

    for i in range(n):
        line.fill(0.0)

        for k in range(m):
            factor = A[i, k]
            for j in range(m):
                line[j] += factor * B[k, j]

        for j in range(i, n):
            for k in range(m):
                C[i, j] += line[k] * A[j, k]

    for i in range(1, A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i):
            C[i, j] = C[j, i]
```

This solution is significantly faster than the provided one. However, it is a bit slower than `A @ B @ A.T`. This is because Numpy uses BLAS libraries to compute matrix multiplications and the BLAS used on my machine is OpenBLAS : a highly-optimized implementation. OpenBLAS performs the matrix multiplication in **parallel** while the above Numba code is sequential. If you plan to run the Numba function from a multithreaded code, then the Numba code will be faster than the one of Numpy. Otherwise, you can parallelize the loop `i` that way:

```py
from numba import prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def faster_fun(A, B, C):
    assert A.shape[1] == B.shape[0] and A.shape[1] == B.shape[1]
    n, m = A.shape

    for i in prange(n):
        line = np.zeros(m)

        # [....] (same code later, but not need for line.fill)

    # [...]
```

This solution is faster than the sequential code on most machine, except for very small matrices (since spawning threads, distributing the work and waiting for them is not free). However, it is still slower than the basic Numpy code `A @ B @ A.T` on my machine. This is because the allocation of `line` does not scale at all. Indeed, the parallel code is only 3.2 times faster than the sequential one on my 6-core CPU. AFAIK, there is no simple solution in Numba to fix this (known) issue yet. In Cython, the solution would be to use a stack allocation or a thread-local one to fix this issue. Still, even with a perfect scaling, the above code would be just 30% faster on 60x60 matrices. This shows how hard it is to outperform highly-optimized BLAS implementations and also that the symmetry only give a **small performance gain** for medium sized-matrices.

Actually, only half of the second matrix multiplication needs to be computed (optimal), but the first certainly needs to be fully computed. Thus, the theoretical optimal gain is certainly 25% which is rather small. That being said, in practice, for very small matrices, the sequential Numba implementation should be significantly faster than the Numpy code (due to the threading overhead).

Comment: I like it. Is openblas faster for small matrices as well?

Comment: Hey, look at my updated solution. What do you think?

Comment: *"Is openblas faster for small matrices as well?"* I am confused. OpenBLAS is the default BLAS used by Numpy on most platforms. This is the BLAS used in the Numpy reference code in my answer. Parallelism is what makes the parallel implementation slow for small matrices (so the Numpy code using OpenBLAS and the Numba parallel implementation). Results are very dependent of the target platform. On computing servers with many core, parallel implementation tends to be even slower on small matrices. You should pick the one matching with your environment and your use-case.

Comment: The new solution you provide is faster than the previous one but still more than 2x slower than the one of the answer (sequential version -- tested on 10x10 matrices). Also note that `A @ B @ A.T` is faster than the 2 calls to `np.matmul` on my machine.